# Gatling j.n.ConnectException: Address already in use

Tags: gatling

When running simulations with Gatling I get the following exceptions:

> j.n.ConnectException: Address already in use: no further information

Does this occur when the server tested against fails to respond or timeout?
I want to make sure this is a exception thrown by the server and not by the client.

Comment: Any update on this? Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Let me  try out and get back to you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I also encountered this problem running Gatling (with a lot of requests, > 100 RPS) on Windows. It seems Windows is running out of ephemeral ports to use. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/-ZjLD1EA4yQ) in the user group forum. So this is not a problem with your system under test, but with the machine running Gatling.

On Windows, you can [see and change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista) your ephemeral port range using the `netsh` command. You can use following commands to

- see your currently configured IPv4 port range for TCP:

  ```
  netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
  ```
- change the port range:

  ```
  netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=number num=range
  ```

---

E.g., I increased my ephemeral IPv4 TCP port range like so to resolve the problem:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=1025 num=57975
```

Comment: (Run as administrator)