# What is a good starting number port when changing the ephemeral IPv4 TCP port range?

Tags: windows, scala, gatling, ipv4

I ran into the same issue that is described in this question: 
[Gatling j.n.ConnectException: Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969010/gatling-j-n-connectexception-address-already-in-use)

One answer suggests changing the ephemeral port range like this:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=1025 num=57975
```

I did try it and it does work, however my question is about the number of the start port (1025 in this example). 
I'm afraid of setting a number that would cause some issues.

I have been able to find information about the range (with the max being 65535), but not much about the start port.

So my question is what would be a good number for the start port?

What do I need to worry about when changing it?